# Typescript - What is the difference between an observable put request subscribe using the arrow and no arrow?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I apologize if the title is not worded well. In my angular codebase I can see two different put requests:

```
  public Save() {
    const types: string[] = this.getTypes.getCurrentTypes();
    this.userTypeService
      .updateTypes(this.userID, groups)
      .subscribe(() => {
        showToast("success", "User types Updated.");
      });
  }
```

where updateTypes is a function that makes a simple httpPut request.

What is the difference between this, and a duplicate function that uses

```
.subscribe( 
showToast("success", "user types updated");
)
```

Basically, what is the functionality of the () => in subscribe? Also, is there any good way to catch an error from the call using this way?

EDIT: I figured it out, the answer below works for me:

```
public Save() {
    const types: string[] = this.getTypes.getCurrentTypes();
    this.userTypeService
      .updateTypes(this.userID, groups)
      .subscribe(() => {
        result => showToast("success", "User types Updated.");
        error => showToast("error", "Error");
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.subscribe( 
  showToast("success", "user types updated");
)
```

If the semicolon is removed to fix the syntax error, then this will call `showToast` *immediately* and pass whatever the return value is into `.subscribe`. The only way this pattern would make sense is if `showToast` is a factory function which creates and returns other functions, but given the name i don't think that's likely. Assuming `showToast` returns `undefined`, no subscription will be created.

In short: this is probably a bug.

The first way you showed is the right way to create a function, and pass that function into subscribe, so that it will be called later.

> is there any good way to catch an error from the call

To handle errors, you'll pass in a second function to subscribe, telling it what you want to do when the error occurs. For example:

```
.subscribe(
  (result) => {
    showToast("success", "user types updated")
  }, // <--- this function is the same as before, and handles the success case
  (error) => {
    showToast("failure", error)
  } // <--- this function is new and handles the error case.
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. So, with the first way, if I wanted to handle an error that might come from the call, what would be the best way to do this? And sorry I'm very new to angular - so that is creating a function and passing it into subscribe? How can I call it later to get the "showtoast" to execute?

Comment: The `.subscribe` on [observables](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview) lets you pass in 3 functions. The first is called any time the observable successfully emits a value, the second will be called when it emits an error, the third will be called when it completes. So you would handle errors by passing in that second function (you shouldn't need the third for your case)

Comment: `How can I call it later to get the "showtoast" to execute?` Assuming the updateTypes function is written in a sensible way, you don't need to do anything other than pass the function into `subscribe` like you're already doing. Your function will be called automatically once updateTypes is done.

Comment: I noticed in the edited response you show it as .subscribe( 
(result)
(error)
);

instead of .subscribe(() => {, like the way you said was correct - could I just add the error to it? I'll edit the main question.

Comment: Are you talking about the fact that i left out the curly brackets? Arrow functions have a shorthand where you can leave out the curly brackets if there's only one statement in the body of the function. You still need to create a function (or two functions if you need the error case). I've updated the code to remove the shorthand.